# What's the different between perspectiveLH and perspectiveFieldOfViewLH , and did they all perspective to CVV or NDC?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, 3d, stage3d

i have a little confuse about the two function , **perspectiveLH** and
**perspectiveFieldOfViewLH**

first i can derivation the matrix used in perspectiveLH  which is

```
this.copyRawDataFrom(Vector.<Number>([
2.0 * zNear / width, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 2.0 * zNear / height, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, zFar / (zFar - zNear), 1.0,
0.0, 0.0, zNear * zFar / (zNear - zFar), 0.0
 ]));
```

if i am understand correct, use this matrix can perspective world point(WPx ,WPy,Wpz) to **CVV**(Canonical View Volume) or call as **NDC**(Normalized Device Coordinates) point (CPx',CPy',CPz')

but the matrix use in perspectiveFieldOfViewLH which is

```
var yScale:Number = 1.0 / Math.tan(fieldOfViewY / 2.0);
var xScale:Number = yScale / aspectRatio;
this.copyRawDataFrom(Vector.<Number>([
xScale, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, yScale, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, zFar / (zFar - zNear), 1.0,
0.0, 0.0, (zNear * zFar) / (zNear - zFar), 0.0
 ]));
```

i don't understand what xScale and yScale means.

i know we can set the matrix by FOV(Field Of View),but seem my calculate is different from  1.0 / Math.tan(fieldOfViewY / 2.0)

[image]

[image]

if you need more info about my calculate,please check this link:

http://blog.csdn.net/popy007/article/details/4091967

sorry Is not write in English (also not wrote by me)

also , in this article demo code

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/perspective-projection.html

```
projectionTransform = new PerspectiveMatrix3D();
var aspect:Number = 4 / 3;
var zNear:Number = 0.1;
var zFar:Number = 1000;
var fov:Number = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
projectionTransform.perspectiveFieldOfViewLH(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
//projectionTransform.perspectiveLH(800, 600, 0.1, 1000);
```

the perspectiveFieldOfViewLH matrix work fine , but if i change the matrix to

`projectionTransform.perspectiveLH(800, 600, 0.1, 1000)`

then can not get any graph

but use normal  perspective matrix or FOV matrix shoud get the same result right?

i aslo a little bit confuse about Stage3D rendering pipeline, if use those perspective  will convert world point to CVV point , which will deformation.

Does Stage3D will turn the  deformationed graph back to normal during the rasterization, or i need to do it manually. or i just completely wrong about the  rendering pipeline.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any magic happening here. The matrix created by both functions is exactly the same, they just accept different parameters, based on what is most convenient for your environment.

For example, the second term in the second column of the "perspectiveLH" matrix is:

```
2.0 * zNear / height
```

which is equal to the respective term of the "perspectiveFieldOfViewLH" matrix:

```
1.0 / Math.tan(fieldOfViewY / 2.0)
```

If you equate these two, and solve for height with all other known values, you get:

```
height = 2.0 * zNear * tan(fovY / 2) = 2.0 * 0.1 * tan(22.5) = 0.0828
```

Notice, this is not **600** as you were attempting to use. The mistake you made is that the width and height of the perspectiveLH function are not the pixels of the final view, but instead describe the dimensions of the local view plane (at zNear = 0.1).
Once you realize this, the equation `height = 2.0 * zNear * tan(fovY / 2)` suddenly makes sense!

These two functions really are just an expression of the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Adobe's matrises are somewhat confusing. I'm not use them. You can read how it possible here http://volgogradetzzz.blogspot.ru/2012/07/i-dont-need-flashgeommatrix3d-class.html.
Also, here a good explanation with correct matrices http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb281727(v=vs.85).aspx.
What do you mean under deformation? You apply matrices in some order. Perspective matrix goes last. It is called Model View Projection.